# accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors is not working for WKWebView in a SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, accessibility

In my SwiftUI view, I'm trying to apply the `accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors` property to content loaded inside a WKWebView. But this doesn't seem to work. Turning on smart invert in the settings is still causing the WKWebView content to smart invert.
Any help to achieve this would be appreciated.
Goal is to not invert the colours in WKWebView when Smart Invert is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried below code and its working for me.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyWebView()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct MyWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = false
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui")!))
        // Additional configuration for the web view
        // ...
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        // Update the web view if needed
    }
}
```

Attaching screenshots [image: smart invert is on]of simulator.
[image: response]

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. But if you see the images are still inverted inside the WKWebView (ex. my profile image towards the end). The WKWebView I'm trying to load is primarily made of images and I want the images to not invert. But haven't found a way to make this work.

Comment: When displaying images within a web view, the rendering and accessibility behavior of those images depend on the web content itself and how it handles accessibility features. If the web content is not responding as expected to the "Smart Invert Colors" feature, it is likely due to the way the images are being rendered or the web content's configuration.To address this issue, you may need to consider modifying the web content or the way images are presented within the web view. I am updating the code you can try this out. Thanks

Comment: Also would suggest you to check this Article https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/operating-system-and-browser-accessibility-display-modes/ you can get some idea how to stop inverting your color in your web view by some code. May be that Javascript Func you can inject in your webview for forcing your images not to reflect inverted colors.